# KMDF build types

Tags: winapi, 32bit-64bit, kmdf

When building a kernel mode device driver (KMDF) on Windows with Visual Studio 2013, there are 32 bit and x64 bit build options.  The question is this:  When installing the device drivers on the target machines, will the 32 bit builds run on a 64 bit OS or do I need to make sure to get an x64 build on the 64 bit OS?

(I'm assuming the x64 build won't run on a 32 bit OS, but would appreciate any insight here, as well).

Comment: 32 bit drivers dont run on a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559747.aspx):

Emphasis mine.

> For user-mode applications, 64-bit Windows includes a Windows on
>   Windows (WOW64) thunking layer that enables 32-bit applications to
>   execute (with some performance degradation) on 64-bit versions of
>   Windows. It does this by intercepting 32-bit function calls and
>   converting pointer-precision parameter types to fixed-precision types
>   as appropriate before making the transition to the 64-bit kernel. This
>   conversion process is called thunking.
>   **Note  This thunking is only done for 32-bit applications; 32-bit drivers
>   are not supported on 64-bit versions of Windows.**